# How do I clean this weird JSON data which I extracted from an excel file so that it becomes a proper dictionary?

Tags: python, json

I have an excel file which has a JSON type of data. I extracted the data from the column of that Excel file and converted into dictionary using .to_dict() function. One cell of that column of the excel file looks like this, and there are more rows filled with same kind of data for that column:-

> {\currentPortfolioId":null/"isNewRTQ":true/"isNewInvestmentTenure":true/"isNearTermVolatility":false/"getPath":true/"riskProfile":"Moderate"/"initialInvestment":200000/"cashflowDate":"01-01-2021"/"currentWealth":200000/"goalPriority":"Wish"/"rebalancing":"yearly"/"goalAmount":2000000/"startDate":"16-06-2021"/"endDate":"01-01-2031"/"isNewGoalPriority":true/"infusions":[0/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/0]/"scenario_type":"regular"/"infusion_type":"monthly"/"xforwardForValue":"49.228.234.102:49907/ 13.86.190.104:3072/ 172.30.217.148:36243"}"

As it is visible the data is not cleaned, with special characters like "/", "", "" etc.

Can anyone help me in how to clean this data and convert it into a proper dictionary so that I can later do operations in it?

I did try `ast.literal_eval()` but it doesn't seem to work.
Please help!

Comment: Please include your sample data in the question as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Edited, please check

Answer (score 0):

It's very similar to json. Maybe it was mangled by autocorrect or something like that in Excel? The commas have been replaced with backslash characters and every `"` is prefixed with a slash. Also a single `"` is missing before the first key.

If you add the missing `"`, strip out all `\` and replace `/` with `,` you can parse it with `json.loads()`.

```
data = r'''{\"currentPortfolioId\":null/\"isNewRTQ\":true/\"isNewInvestmentTenure\":true/\"isNearTermVolatility\":false/\"getPath\":true/\"riskProfile\":\"Moderate\"/\"initialInvestment\":200000/\"cashflowDate\":\"01-01-2021\"/\"currentWealth\":200000/\"goalPriority\":\"Wish\"/\"rebalancing\":\"yearly\"/\"goalAmount\":2000000/\"startDate\":\"16-06-2021\"/\"endDate\":\"01-01-2031\"/\"isNewGoalPriority\":true/\"infusions\":[0/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/0]/\"scenario_type\":\"regular\"/\"infusion_type\":\"monthly\"/\"xforwardForValue\":\"49.228.234.102:49907/ 13.86.190.104:3072/ 172.30.217.148:36243\"}'''

import json
json.loads(data.replace("\\", "").replace("/", ","))
```

Comment: How do i add that missing " ? I was able to remove somehow the "\" and replace "/" with ",".

Comment: I would start by manually adding the ". If there are many excel cells which consistenlty have the data mangled in this specific way, you could use a regular expression to fix it. Ideally you should skip the excel file and get the same data from the original source. But if you are stuck with the excel doc, you must find a pragmatic solution. But since this "data format" doesn't follow any standard, I can't suggest a solution that will work across the entire input spreadsheet. In the next cell the data might be mangled in a slightly different way.

Comment: Thank you for your response, when I removed those characters, i was not able to get a dictionary format, since "" are missing on places, although it comes out as a long string. Anyway I can make that long string converted into a dataframe with the columns being the key values of my dictionary, Ex:- goalAmount, goalPriority, currentwealth, etc. so that the value of those pairs come into the subsequent rows?